# Collection View not printing inside TableViewCell with Autoresize Row in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Problem Statement: Collection View required to be printed inside table view cell and auto resize should work as well 
Thanks

There is a table view cell.
Collection view is required to be printed.
Auto resizing of Table View cell works well without Collection View
When Collection view is added then it doesnt work.
Collection view is printed if Height of the cell by heightOfRow method is used
But if it is not used then the collection view methods are not called even.

Constraints from IB have been added but still not working. 
In the following you can see the Example view controller

import UIKit
    import AVFoundation

```
let studentName = ["Stockholm","London","Paris","Oslo"]


class TableViewController: UITableViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140

        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension


        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }
    /*
     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
     return 300
     }*/


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return studentName.count
        //  return 0
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell



        cell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(dataSourceDelegate: self, forRow: indexPath.row)


        cell.secondName.text = "Second Name is Here"
        cell.firstName.text = studentName[indexPath.row]
        print("cell height is == \(cell.frame.size.height)")
        // Configure the cell...

        return cell
    }

    // All collection view methods
    @available(iOS 6.0, *)


    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionViewReuseIdentifier", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! myCollectionViewCell
        cell.collection_first.text = "1"

        cell.Collection_second.text = "2"
        print("in collection view number of items in section---cell--\(indexPath.row)--")
        return cell

    }

    @available(iOS 6.0, *)


    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("in collection view number of items in section---\(studentName.count)")
        return studentName.count
    }


    /*
     func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

     return  2

     }
     //
     //    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     //
     //        return 5
     //    }

     func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

     let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionViewReuseIdentifier", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! myCollectionViewCell

     //.......cell configure....

     return cell

     }


     func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

     print("get selected collectionview itemindex \(indexPath.row)")

     }
     */


    //}
    /*
     // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
     // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
     return true
     }
     */

    /*
     // Override to support editing the table view.
     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     if editingStyle == .delete {
     // Delete the row from the data source
     tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
     } else if editingStyle == .insert {
     // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
     }
     }
     */

    /*
     // Override to support rearranging the table view.
     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt fromIndexPath: IndexPath, to: IndexPath) {

     }
     */

    /*
     // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
     // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
     return true
     }
     */

    /*
     // MARK: - Navigation

     // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
     override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
     // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     }
     */

}
```